# How to I assign each variable in a list, a number, and then add the numbers up for the same variables?

Tags: python, list

For example, if `ZZAZAAZ` is input, the sum of `A` would be `14` (since its placement is `3,5,6`), while the sum of `Z` would be `14` `(1 + 2 + 4 + 7)`.

How would I do that?

Comment: If you are going to ask questions like this you should at least show that you have tried to write some code.

Comment: There's no `B` in that input

Answer (score 10):

You can use a generator expression within `sum` :

```
>>> s='ZZAZAAZ'
>>> sum(i for i,j in enumerate(s,1) if j=='A')
14
```

Answer (score 1):

For all the elements in `s` you could do this. Also, it would find the counts for each element in a single pass of the string `s`, hence it's linear in the number of elements in `s`.

```
>>> s = 'ZZAZAAZ'
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, item in enumerate(s):
    ... d[item] = d.get(item, 0) + i + 1
>>> print d
{'A': 14, 'Z': 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthering [Kasra's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29734859/4686625) of using `enumerate`, if you wanted a dictionary containing these sums you could use a dictionary comprehension, and iterate over the set of unique characters, like so:

```
>>> s = 'ZZAZAAZ' 
>>> {let:sum(a for a,b in enumerate(s,1) if b==let) for let in set(s)}
{'Z': 14, 'A': 14}
```